# Gson VerifyError - JsonTreeReader is not assignable to JsonReader

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to use GSON and am running into an issue. I've added the library as a Maven dependency and everything else, and it should work just fine. However, whenever I construct a new instance of `Gson`, I get the following error:

```
Exception:
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/gson/Gson.fromJson(Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object; @16: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeReader' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader'
```

And though the error seems pretty standard, it doesn't really make any sense. For example, in the decompiled binary from `Gson.class`, I see:

`return json == null?null:this.fromJson((JsonReader)(new JsonTreeReader(json)), (Type)typeOfT);`

So clearly `JsonTreeReader` is meant to be assignable to `JsonReader`. My code is quite simple. Literally:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

I've tried multiple versions of the package, so it can't be that. I am using AEM (OSGI) but I don't think that's related, because on another very similar project, I'm using Gson just fine.

I'm not a huge Java guy, so would love some insight on this error and things I can try to debug.

Full Stack Trace:

```
Bad type on operand stack Exception Details: Location: com/google/gson/Gson.fromJson(Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object; @16: invokevirtual Reason: Type 'com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeReader' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader' Current Frame: bci: @16 flags: { } locals: { 'com/google/gson/Gson', 'com/google/gson/JsonElement', 'java/lang/reflect/Type' } stack: { 'com/google/gson/Gson', 'com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeReader', 'java/lang/reflect/Type' } Bytecode: 0x0000000: 2bc7 0005 01b0 2abb 00c6 592b b700 c72c 0x0000010: b600 b8b0 Stackmap Table: same_frame(@6)
Cannot serve request to /services/time/server in com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet

Exception:
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/gson/Gson.fromJson(Lcom/google/gson/JsonElement;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Ljava/lang/Object; @16: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeReader' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @16
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/gson/Gson', 'com/google/gson/JsonElement', 'java/lang/reflect/Type' }
    stack: { 'com/google/gson/Gson', 'com/google/gson/internal/bind/JsonTreeReader', 'java/lang/reflect/Type' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2bc7 0005 01b0 2abb 00c6 592b b700 c72c
    0x0000010: b600 b8b0                              
  Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@6)

    at com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet.doGet(ServerTimeServlet.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:270)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:346)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:378)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:71)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:436)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:154)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:180)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:221)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:73)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:79)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:138)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:74)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:128)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Request Progress:
      0 TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      2 COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed microseconds>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      6 LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=null
      9 TIMER_START{handleSecurity}
    899 TIMER_END{888,handleSecurity} authenticator org.apache.sling.auth.core.impl.SlingAuthenticator@1f443744 returns true
   1102 TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
   1165 TIMER_END{62,ResourceResolution} URI=/services/time/server resolves to Resource=ServletResource, servlet=com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet, path=/services/time/server
   1171 LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/services/time/server', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='null'
   1171 TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
   1173 TIMER_START{resolveServlet(/services/time/server)}
   1182 TIMER_END{7,resolveServlet(/services/time/server)} Using servlet com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet
   1184 TIMER_END{12,ServletResolution} URI=/services/time/server handled by Servlet=com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet
   1188 LOG Applying Requestfilters
   1192 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl
   1197 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
   1199 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter
   1208 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
   1210 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker
   1235 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter
   1353 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
   1361 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter
   1365 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
   1368 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter
   1370 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
   1371 LOG Calling filter: com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter
   1374 LOG Calling filter: com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter
   1377 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
   1378 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl
   1465 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter
   1467 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter
   1470 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter
   1472 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl
   1475 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter
   1482 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler
   1708 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler
   1773 LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet
   1777 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
   1783 LOG Applying Componentfilters
   1784 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter
   1786 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
   1857 LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
   1863 TIMER_START{com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet#0}
   2493 TIMER_END{629,com.mycompany.core.servlets.ServerTimeServlet#0}
   2521 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   2522 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   2545 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.dam.webdav.impl.io.DamWebdavRequestFilter, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   2546 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   2547 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet, inner=0, total=0, outer=0
   2549 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler, inner=0, total=1, outer=1
   2550 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2552 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.DamContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2553 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2555 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2556 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2557 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2558 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2560 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2561 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2562 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2563 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.mycompany.core.filters.LoggingFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2564 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2566 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2567 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2568 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2569 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2570 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2571 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2573 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2574 LOG Filter timing: filter=com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2576 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2579 LOG Filter timing: filter=org.apache.sling.distribution.servlet.DistributionAgentCreationFilter, inner=1, total=1, outer=0
   2988 LOG Applying Error filters
   2990 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
   2991 LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
   2998 TIMER_START{handleError:throwable=java.lang.VerifyError}
   3481 TIMER_END{482,handleError:throwable=java.lang.VerifyError} Using handler /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/default.jsp
   4354 LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html], order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobile: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-mobiledebug: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), Config(type=contentsync, config=JcrPropertyMap [node=Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/libs/cq/config/rewriter/default/transformer-contentsync: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, component-optional = true}}], values={jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured, component-optional=true}]), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
   4830 TIMER_END{4828,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm also on AEM and suddenly seeing this issue.

Comment: So it ends up that GSON is bundled already with AEM as an OSGI service, so I used that instead - it's a very specific version, but it works. I literally removed GSON from all of my pom files and just used it, and it worked.